# Joomla template issues

Tags: css, templates, html

I'm working on a website for a school project, I'm using a template called quantua. If you go to live demo of the template ( http://www.templatesjoomla.net/index.php/joomla3-x/244-quantua-joomla-3-x.html ), you can see that when resizing the browser window the image shrinks so much that a black background appears. I don't want it to do that, how can the resizing be achived like on this  (http://www.websitetemplatesonline.com/free-template/progress-business.html) template? I played with css quite a bit, but i failed, so I guess it has to do with javascript?

heres the javascript code

```
(function($) {
    var NivoSlider = function(element, options){
        // Defaults are below
        var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.nivoSlider.defaults, options);

        // Useful variables. Play carefully.
        var vars = {
            currentSlide: 0,
            currentImage: '',
            totalSlides: 0,
            running: false,
            paused: false,
            stop: false,
            controlNavEl: false
        };

        // Get this slider
        var slider = $(element);
        slider.data('nivo:vars', vars).addClass('nivoSlider');

        // Find our slider children
        var kids = slider.children();
        kids.each(function() {
            var child = $(this);
            var link = '';
            if(!child.is('img')){
                if(child.is('a')){
                    child.addClass('nivo-imageLink');
                    link = child;
                }
                child = child.find('img:first');
            }
            // Get img width & height
            var childWidth = (childWidth === 0) ? child.attr('width') : child.width(),
                childHeight = (childHeight === 0) ? child.attr('height') : child.height();

            if(link !== ''){
                link.css('display','none');
            }
            child.css('display','none');
            vars.totalSlides++;
        });

        // If randomStart
        if(settings.randomStart){
            settings.startSlide = Math.floor(Math.random() * vars.totalSlides);
        }

        // Set startSlide
        if(settings.startSlide > 0){
            if(settings.startSlide >= vars.totalSlides) { settings.startSlide = vars.totalSlides - 1; }
            vars.currentSlide = settings.startSlide;
        }

        // Get initial image
        if($(kids[vars.currentSlide]).is('img')){
            vars.currentImage = $(kids[vars.currentSlide]);
        } else {
            vars.currentImage = $(kids[vars.currentSlide]).find('img:first');
        }

        // Show initial link
        if($(kids[vars.currentSlide]).is('a')){
            $(kids[vars.currentSlide]).css('display','block');
        }

        // Set first background
        var sliderImg = $('<img class="nivo-main-image" src="#" />');
        sliderImg.attr('src', vars.currentImage.attr('src')).show();
        slider.append(sliderImg);

        // Detect Window Resize
        $(window).resize(function() {
            slider.children('img').width(slider.width());
            sliderImg.attr('src', vars.currentImage.attr('src'));
            sliderImg.stop().height('auto');
            $('.nivo-slice').remove();
            $('.nivo-box').remove();
        });

        //Create caption
        slider.append($('<div class="nivo-caption"></div>'));

        // Process caption function
        var processCaption = function(settings){
            var nivoCaption = $('.nivo-caption', slider);
            if(vars.currentImage.attr('title') != '' && vars.currentImage.attr('title') != undefined){
                var title = vars.currentImage.attr('title');
                if(title.substr(0,1) == '#') title = $(title).html();   

                if(nivoCaption.css('display') == 'block'){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        nivoCaption.html(title);
                    }, settings.animSpeed);
                } else {
                    nivoCaption.html(title);
                    nivoCaption.stop().fadeIn(settings.animSpeed);
                }
            } else {
                nivoCaption.stop().fadeOut(settings.animSpeed);
            }
        }

        //Process initial  caption
        processCaption(settings);

        // In the words of Super Mario "let's a go!"
        var timer = 0;
        if(!settings.manualAdvance && kids.length > 1){
            timer = setInterval(function(){ nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, false); }, settings.pauseTime);
        }

        // Add Direction nav
        if(settings.directionNav){
            slider.append('<div class="nivo-directionNav"><a class="nivo-prevNav">'+ settings.prevText +'</a><a class="nivo-nextNav">'+ settings.nextText +'</a></div>');

            // Hide Direction nav
            if(settings.directionNavHide){
                $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).hide();
                slider.hover(function(){
                    $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).show();
                }, function(){
                    $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).hide();
                });
            }

            $('a.nivo-prevNav', slider).live('click', function(){
                if(vars.running) { return false; }
                clearInterval(timer);
                timer = '';
                vars.currentSlide -= 2;
                nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'prev');
            });

            $('a.nivo-nextNav', slider).live('click', function(){
                if(vars.running) { return false; }
                clearInterval(timer);
                timer = '';
                nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'next');
            });
        }

        // Add Control nav
        if(settings.controlNav){
            vars.controlNavEl = $('<div class="nivo-controlNav"></div>');
            slider.after(vars.controlNavEl);
            for(var i = 0; i < kids.length; i++){
                if(settings.controlNavThumbs){
                    vars.controlNavEl.addClass('nivo-thumbs-enabled');
                    var child = kids.eq(i);
                    if(!child.is('img')){
                        child = child.find('img:first');
                    }
                    if(child.attr('data-thumb')) vars.controlNavEl.append('<a class="nivo-control" rel="'+ i +'"><img src="'+ child.attr('data-thumb') +'" alt="" /></a>');
                } else {
                    vars.controlNavEl.append('<a class="nivo-control" rel="'+ i +'">'+ (i + 1) +'</a>');
                }
            }

            //Set initial active link
            $('a:eq('+ vars.currentSlide +')', vars.controlNavEl).addClass('active');

            $('a', vars.controlNavEl).bind('click', function(){
                if(vars.running) return false;
                if($(this).hasClass('active')) return false;
                clearInterval(timer);
                timer = '';
                sliderImg.attr('src', vars.currentImage.attr('src'));
                vars.currentSlide = $(this).attr('rel') - 1;
                nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'control');
            });
        }

        //For pauseOnHover setting
        if(settings.pauseOnHover){
            slider.hover(function(){
                vars.paused = true;
                clearInterval(timer);
                timer = '';
            }, function(){
                vars.paused = false;
                // Restart the timer
                if(timer === '' && !settings.manualAdvance){
                    timer = setInterval(function(){ nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, false); }, settings.pauseTime);
                }
            });
        }

        // Event when Animation finishes
        slider.bind('nivo:animFinished', function(){
            sliderImg.attr('src', vars.currentImage.attr('src'));
            vars.running = false; 
            // Hide child links
            $(kids).each(function(){
                if($(this).is('a')){
                   $(this).css('display','none');
                }
            });
            // Show current link
            if($(kids[vars.currentSlide]).is('a')){
                $(kids[vars.currentSlide]).css('display','block');
            }
            // Restart the timer
            if(timer === '' && !vars.paused && !settings.manualAdvance){
                timer = setInterval(function(){ nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, false); }, settings.pauseTime);
            }
            // Trigger the afterChange callback
            settings.afterChange.call(this);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking in the wrong place. use firebug to inspect and know which css file is being used. the file is default.css. Line 159. Thats what you should be playing with. this is what it looks like

```
.nivoSlider {
float: left;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 480px;
overflow: hidden;
background: #000
```

this is the block of code that affects the presentation of the navigation bar. but to eradicate the blackness down there, you can use this close fix

1. change the property height of the nivoslider class to auto on line 159
2. change the backgroud property of the navigation class from transparent to black on line 296
3. change the margin-top property of the id menu class to 316px on line 285

this is not guaranteed to not distort especially the  last point. but keep trying.

Comment: that didn't do what I want. Now the image gets smaller but insted of the black the published article goes there...If I try to describe better.. how to I make the slideshow non resizable?